# How do I convert this into a pie chart in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have some data:

[image]

How do I for example display a bar chart or pie chart of the workbook-languages are listed?

- 43 is once
- 6 is twice
- 3 is once

etc. The actual descriptions for these numbers (the languages) are in column G.

Comment: Hi, refer to this https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-a-pie-chart-1a5f08ae-ba40-46f2-9ed0-ff84873b7863

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a pivot table. Rows would be workbook-languages, and Count would be count of workbook languages. Then create a pivot chart. If you would rather display the language instead of the code, then use your Column G for rows. Just make sure the count section is count rather than sum.

Also, "6" is listed four times, not twice, in your screenshot. If you are worried about duplicates (ie, 6 is listed twice for the same day and you only want to count that once), then do this... When you create your pivot table, select the check box for "add this data to a data model". Then your rows is your language, and your count is the count of dates. Then right-click on that count column, select "Value Field Settings", and then change your Summarize value to "Distinct Count".

Comment: Thanks. I have managed to make the pivot table but I can't work out how to make the pivot chart from that data on screen.

Comment: I tried to select just the pivot table cell and then create a pivot chart and I selected pie chart. But I see no pie. :)

Comment: Sorted! :) Thanks